# Copying entire row from one excel sheet to next empty row of another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets `data` and `PrevErrCheck`. I am checking all occurrence of variable `VarVal`(this variable has data in E1 cell of `PrevErrCheck`) in sheet data and copy entire row to sheet `PrevErrCheck`. But the problem I am facing here is running macro multiple times overwriting data. I would like to keep the copied rows in sheet data and whenever I run next time, it should copy to next blank row.

I am using below code currently but bit confused to how to integrate the the option to find last row on `PrevErrCheck` and copy lines below that

```
Sub PrevErrCheck()    
    Dim spem As Workbook
    Dim PrevErrCheck As Worksheet
    Dim data As Worksheet
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long

    Set spem = Excel.Workbooks("SwitchPortErrorMonitor.xlsm")
    Set PrevErrCheck = spem.Worksheets("PrevErrCheck")
    Set data = spem.Worksheets("data")

    spem.Worksheets("PrevErrCheck").Activate 
    VarVal = PrevErrCheck.Cells(1, "E").Value
    I = data.UsedRange.Rows.count
    J = PrevErrCheck.UsedRange.Rows.count

    If J = 1 Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(PrevErrCheck.UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If

    Set xRg = data.Range("X:X")
    On Error Resume Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    J = 3
    For K = 1 To xRg.count      
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = VarVal And Not IsEmpty(VarVal) Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=PrevErrCheck.Range("A" & J + 1)
            PrevErrCheck.Range("X" & J + 1).ClearContents
            J = J + 1
        End If    
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So you are getting an error? Which error and on which line? Please include that in your question.

Comment: `J = J + 1` maybe

Comment: First of all remove `On Error Resume Next`. This statement makes you blind during debuging, it mutes all error messages but the errors still occur. This should **never** be used without a proper error handling!

Answer (score 0):

You have `J = 3` before the loop, that may be a problem. `xRg.count` always returns 1048576, you should use something more specific. Try this:

```
Set spem = Excel.Workbooks("SwitchPortErrorMonitor.xlsm")
Set PrevErrCheck = spem.Worksheets("PrevErrCheck")
VarVal = PrevErrCheck.Cells(1, "E").Value
If IsEmpty(VarVal) Then Exit Sub

Set data = spem.Worksheets("data")

spem.Worksheets("PrevErrCheck").Activate
I = data.UsedRange.Rows.Count
J = PrevErrCheck.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
If J = 2 Then
    If IsEmpty(PrevErrCheck.Cells(1, 1)) Then J = 1
End If

'    If J = 1 Then
'        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(PrevErrCheck.UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
'    End If

'    Set xRg = data.Range("X:X")
'    On Error Resume Next

'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'    J = 3
For K = 1 To I
    If CStr(data.Cells(K, "X").Value) = VarVal Then
        data.Cells(K, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=PrevErrCheck.Range("A" & J)
        PrevErrCheck.Range("X" & J).ClearContents
        J = J + 1
    End If
Next

'   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```